# Retrieving an ajax request in json format in a php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

```
$('.addFormForm').submit(function(){
        //requête ajax permettant l'envoie de formulaire au controleur
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            //chargement du controleur
            url : 'gestionForm.php',
            //passage des données au controler
            data : {dataJson: test123},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response); 
            }
        })
    });
```

Hi, here is my ajax request where I send a json structure : "test123" to the page : gestionForm,
There is gestionForm :

```
$data = $_POST["dataJson"];
if(isset($_POST['submitForm'])){
    $obj = new Form($_POST['nomForm'], $data);
    $obj->getIDPage($_POST['nomPage']);
    $obj->addForm();
}
```

And I get the error :
`Undefined array key "dataJson"`

Can someone help me pls?

Comment: try `var_dump($_POST)` before your `if` statement and show us what you get.

Comment: test123 is a json structure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Comment: with var_dump($_post) i get : array(3) { ["nomForm"]=> string(7) "azeadza" ["nomPage"]=> string(16) "Bloc Opératoire" ["submitForm"]=> string(7) "envoyer" } so I don't see dataJson

Comment: `$('.addFormForm').submit(function(){ ..ajax ..` is that *all* that's in `.addFormFrom` submit?   Looks like your FORM is POSTing because you've not cancelled the submit.  Add `return false;` as the last line, after (and outside) `$.ajax`

Comment: try `$('.addFormForm').submit(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); //... rest }`

Comment: `test123 is a json structure` ... you mean it's a string in JSON format? Or a JavaScript object? It's unclear. If it's JSON, then send the whole request as JSON...don't wrap JSON inside form-url-encoded data (which is what jQuery will transform your data object to), that's just nonsensical. But if it's actually still an object, them stop referring to it as JSON, because it isn't JSON.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need to pass the values in gestionForm.php as Array

```
$output = array
    (
     //your values
    );

echo json_encode($output);
```

And echo it as output...
Note: In AJAX, use the following parameters...

```
    dataType:"JSON",
    success:function(data)
```

Hope this helps (:

Comment: question is about sending data from JS to PHP, not the other way round